# Running a Tensorflow model on Android

Tags: android, tensorflow, bazel

I'm trying to figure out the workflow for training and deploying a Tensorflow model on Android.  I'm aware of the other questions similar to this one on StackOverflow, but none of them seem to address the problems I've run into.

After studying the Android example from the Tensorflow repository, this is what I think the workflow should be:

1. Build and train Tensorflow model in Python.
2. Create a new graph, and transfer all relevant nodes (i.e. not the nodes responsible for training) to this new graph.  Trained weight variables are imported as constants so that the C++ API can read them.
3. Develop Android GUI in Java, using the native keyword to stub out a call to the Tensorflow model.
4. Run javah to generate the C/C++ stub code for the Tensorflow native call.
5. Fill in the stub by using the Tensorflow C++ API to read in and access the trained/serialized model.
6. Use Bazel to build BOTH the Java app, the native Tensorflow interface (as a .so file), and generate the APK.
7. Use adb to deploy the APK.

   Step 6 is the problem.  Bazel will happily compile a native (to OSX) .dylib that I can call from Java via the JNI.  Android Studio, likewise, will generate a whole bunch of XML code that makes the GUI I want.  However, Bazel wants all of the java app code to be inside the 'WORKSPACE' top-level directory (in the Tensorflow repo), and Android Studio immediately links in all sorts of external libraries from the SDK to make GUIs (I know because my Bazel compile run fails when it can't find these resources).  The only way I can find to force Bazel to cross-compile a .so file is by making it a dependent rule of an Android rule.  Directly cross-compiling a native lib is what I'd prefer to porting my A.S. code to a Bazel project.

   How do I square this?  Bazel will supposedly compile Android code, but Android Studio generates code that Bazel can't compile.  All the examples from Google simply give you code from a repo without any clue as to how it was generated.  As far as I know, the XML that's part of an Android Studio app is supposed to be generated, not made by hand.  If it can be made by hand, how do I avoid the need for all those external libraries?

   Maybe I'm getting the workflow wrong, or there's some aspect of Bazel/Android Studio that I'm not understanding.  Any help appreciated.

Thanks!

**Edit:**

There were several things that I ended up doing that might have contributed to the library building successfully:

1. I upgraded to the latest Bazel.
2. I rebuilt TensorFlow from source.
3. I implemented the recommended Bazel BUILD file below, with a few additions (taken from the Android example):

   ```
   cc_binary(
   name = "libName.so",
   srcs = ["org_tensorflowtest_MyActivity.cc", 
           "org_tensorflowtest_MyActivity.h",
           "jni.h",
           "jni_md.h",
           ":libpthread.so"],
   deps = ["//tensorflow/core:android_tensorflow_lib",
           ],
   copts = [
       "-std=c++11",
       "-mfpu=neon",
       "-O2",
   ],
   linkopts = ["-llog -landroid -lm"],
   linkstatic = 1,
   linkshared = 1,
   )

   cc_binary(
        name = "libpthread.so",
        srcs = [],
        linkopts = ["-shared"],
        tags = [
            "manual",
            "notap",
        ],
   )
   ```

I haven't verified that this library can be loaded and used in Android yet; Android Studio 1.5 seems to be very finicky about acknowledging the presence of native libs.

Comment: Making a .dylib will not help at all, as Android isn't OSX-  dylib is an OSX only format.  It's linux, you need to build a .so (which is pretty much the same thing feature wise, but a different file format).  Also, the XML in Android is all made by hand NOT generated.  Pretty much nothing in any of the Google examples is generated.  The fact you're expecting it to be is probably part of your problem.

Comment: Also, unless your Tensorflow software needs to use Bazel, I've never heard of it being used for Android work.  Gradle is the new standard, and Ant is the legacy standard.  If you're using Bazel you're either bleeding edge or completely doing your own thing.

Comment: @amm Were you able to run it on android what is the size of the app you built?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After setting up an Android NDK in your WORKSPACE file, Bazel can cross-compile a .so for Android, like this:

```
cc_binary(
    name = "libfoo.so",
    srcs = ["foo.cc"],
    deps = [":bar"],
    linkstatic = 1,
    linkshared = 1,
)

$ bazel build foo:libfoo.so \
    --crosstool_top=//external:android/crosstool --cpu=armeabi-v7a \
    --host_crosstool_top=@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain
$ file bazel-bin/foo/libfoo.so
bazel-bin/foo/libfoo.so: ELF 32-bit LSB  shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), not stripped
```

> Bazel wants all of the java app code to be inside the 'WORKSPACE'
>   top-level directory (in the Tensorflow repo)

When 0.1.4 is released (pushing it right now) and we have pushed some fixes to TensorFlow and Protobuf, you can start using the TensorFlow repo as a remote repository. After setting it up in your WORKSPACE file, you can then refer to TensorFlow rules using `@tensorflow//foo/bar` labels.

Comment: Since you most likely a member of the [Bazel group](https://github.com/ulfjack/bazel/graphs/contributors) can you note it in your [SO profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4731056/ulf-adams). I am more apt to upvote an answer if I know the person answering is a member of the development team.

Comment: What I mean by the comment: I cannot keep my app code in a directory structure separate from the Tensorflow root.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me.  Error message:  "ERROR: No toolchain found for cpu 'darwin'."   I have android_sdk_repository() and android_ndk_repository() defined in my WORKSPACE file.

Comment: You're right, it doesn't work yet. I should have actually tried the instructions before posting, sorry about that. I updated the instructions just now, and they work for me. (I also updated my profile to indicate that I work on Bazel.)

Comment: My build still fails with the same issue (No toolchain found for cpu 'darwin').  This might have something to do with the CROSSTOOL file.  My install appears to have only one of them in third_party/gpus/crosstool/.

Comment: @UlfAdams Thank for the SO profile update. Nice to know.

Comment: I don't know how I managed to mess up the instructions again. I thought I had copy-pasted them in. Now they should work - note the additional --host_crosstool_top flag. It's silly, but it's currently required. :-/

Answer (score 1):

```
git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git
```

Note: --recurse-submodules is important to pull submodules.

Install Bazel from here. Bazel is the primary build system for TensorFlow.
Now, edit the WORKSPACE, we can find the WORKSPACE file in the root directory of the TensorFlow that we have cloned earlier.

```
# Uncomment and update the paths in these entries to build the Android demo.
#android_sdk_repository(
#    name = "androidsdk",
#    api_level = 23,
#    build_tools_version = "25.0.1",
#    # Replace with path to Android SDK on your system
#    path = "<PATH_TO_SDK>",
#)
#
#android_ndk_repository(
#    name="androidndk",
#    path="<PATH_TO_NDK>",
#    api_level=14)
```

Like below with our sdk and ndk path:

```
android_sdk_repository(
    name = "androidsdk",
    api_level = 23,
    build_tools_version = "25.0.1",
    # Replace with path to Android SDK on your system
    path = "/Users/amitshekhar/Library/Android/sdk/",
)
android_ndk_repository(
    name="androidndk",
    path="/Users/amitshekhar/Downloads/android-ndk-r13/",
    api_level=14)
```

Then build the .so file.

```
bazel build -c opt //tensorflow/contrib/android:libtensorflow_inference.so \
   --crosstool_top=//external:android/crosstool \
   --host_crosstool_top=@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain \
   --cpu=armeabi-v7a
```

Replacing armeabi-v7a with our desired target architecture.
The library will be located at:

```
bazel-bin/tensorflow/contrib/android/libtensorflow_inference.so
```

To build the Java counterpart:

```
bazel build //tensorflow/contrib/android:android_tensorflow_inference_java
```

We can find the JAR file at:

```
bazel-bin/tensorflow/contrib/android/libandroid_tensorflow_inference_java.jar
```

Now we have both jar and .so file. I have already built both .so file and jar, you can directly use from the [project](https://github.com/MindorksOpenSource/AndroidTensorFlowMachineLearningExample).

Put libandroid_tensorflow_inference_java.jar in libs folder and right click and add as library.

```
compile files('libs/libandroid_tensorflow_inference_java.jar')
```

Create jniLibs folder in main directory and put libtensorflow_inference.so in jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/ folder.

Now, we will be able to call TensorFlow Java API.

The TensorFlow Java API has exposed all the required methods through a class TensorFlowInferenceInterface.

Now, we have to call the TensorFlow Java API with the model path and load it.

I have written a complete blog [here](https://blog.mindorks.com/android-tensorflow-machine-learning-example-ff0e9b2654cc).

Comment: When I run`bazel build //tensorflow/contrib/android:android_tensorflow_inference_java`, I get this error
`ERROR: /tensorflow-1.5.0/WORKSPACE:20:1: no such package '@androidsdk//': android_sdk_repository requires that at least one Android SDK Platform is installed in the Android SDK. Please install an Android SDK Platform through the Android SDK manager. and referenced by '//external:android/sdk'
ERROR: Analysis of target '//tensorflow/contrib/android:android_tensorflow_inference_java' failed; build aborted: Loading failed`